# How to print 6 digit OTP number in shell

Tags: shell-script

I have written a script that generate 6 digit random OTP number
Is there any simple approach to get 6 digit OTP number with less lines of code [Concise code]

**My code :**

```
#!/bin/bash

dynamic_array=()

for (( i =1 ; i<=5 ; i++))
{
    store_digit=$(shuf -i0-9 -n1) ; dynamic_array+=("$store_digit")
}
str_array_value="${dynamic_array[*]}" ; echo "Output : ${str_array_value// /}"
```

Comment: `for ((i=1; i<=6; i++)); do printf "%d" $((RANDOM %10)); done; echo`, subject to there being a very slight bias away from 8 and 9

Comment: `printf '%06d\n' "$(shuf -i0-999999 -n1)"` perhaps?

Comment: @steeldriver can you explain command in detail : `printf '%06d\n' "$(shuf -i0-999999 -n1)"`

Comment: @codeholic24 if you check the manpage for the `shuf` command you will see that it accepts a `-iLO-HI` range. The `printf` command just ensures that the result is printed exactly 6 digits wide i.e. adds leading zeros as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate *actual* OTP tokens generated from a shared secret, and not just random six-digit strings you have no way of verifying, you can use [`oathtool`](http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/).

Otherwise, steeldriver’s comment should suffice: `printf '%06d\n' "$(shuf -i0-999999 -n1)"`.

Answer (score 0):

For 6 decimal digits, we'll need a random number that's larger than 15-bit. Here, I'll use a 30-bit random:

```bsh
((RND=RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)) ; echo ${RND: -6}
```

---

EDIT: Just a couple of tests, for perspective...

```
~# time for i in {0..2000} ;do printf '%06d\n' "$(shuf -i0-999999 -n1)" >/dev/null ;done

real    0m13.814s
user    0m9.573s
sys     0m4.302s

~# time for i in {0..2000} ;do ((RND=RANDOM<<15|RANDOM)) ; echo ${RND: -6} >/dev/null ;done

real    0m0.120s
user    0m0.101s
sys     0m0.019s
```

Answer (score 0):

The question can be re-defined as: "Output a random 6-character string containing characters from a subset of UTF-8: {0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9}".

This leads to:

```
cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 0-9 | head -c 6
```

Comment: That is rather wasteful. `base64` encode the random output and get digits from that, at least.